# How to change EC key size

Tags: java, configuration, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'd like to change the key size for EC keys, which is 256-bit for Java 8 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC), to something higher for use with TLS as a server (not as a TLS client).

I can see the setting I'd like to change. It's in the SunEC JSSE provider properties (fetched programmatically):

```
KeyPairGenerator.EC KeySize=256
```

I have no idea how to set this value, either as a default for the JVM (e.g. setting in `lib/security/java.security` or via a JVM property), or as a parameter for a TLS setup (which typically accepts configuration only for cipher suites and protocols).

Is there a way to specify the number of bits to use for EC crypto?